# graphql-codegenのtypescript-mock-dataで型情報のimportをimport typeで行いたい

Tags: vue.js

表題のとおりですが、以下の環境でnamed exportエラーが出てしまい困っています。

vue@3.2.47
vite@4.3.1
@graphql-codegen/cli@3.3.1
@graphql-codegen/typescript-operations@3.0.4
@graphql-codegen/typescript@3.0.4
@graphql-codegen-typescript-mock-data@3.5.0

この環境で、型情報とmockデータを自動で生成させるようにしたいと思っています。
codegen.ymlは以下のとおりです。

```
overwrite: true
schema:
  - "src/graphql/schema.json"
generates:
  ./src/mocks/handlers/client.ts:
    config:
      importAllFragments: true
      preResolveTypes: true
      module: "esnext"
      useTypeImports: true
    plugins:
      - typescript
      - typescript-operations
  ./src/mocks/handlers/mocks.ts:
    plugins:
      - typescript-mock-data:
          typesFile: "./client.ts"
          terminateCircularRelationships: true
          useIndexSignature: true
          scalars:
            DateTime: moment
```

configのオプションはよくわかっておらず使っています（chatGPTから案内されて）
これらの環境で、graphql-codegenを実行すると、
client.ts

```
export type CreateProjectInput = {
  id?: InputMaybe<Scalars['ID']>;
  title: Scalars['String'];
};

export type DeleteProjectInput = {
  id: Scalars['ID'];
};
```

mocks.ts

```
import { CreateProjectInput, DeleteProjectInput, ModelBooleanInput, ModelFloatInput, ModelIdInput ・・・ } from './client';
```

このようなファイルが出力されます。この時、export type XXXX = {} は import type { xxxx } from xxxx となってほしいのですが、これを実現する方法がわかりません。import { xxxx } from xxxx だと、named exportエラーとなってしまいます。

解決方法はあるのでしょうか？